# BGE everything white in playmode

Tags: texturing, game-engine, uv, shaders

When I press P to play everything shows up white in the BGE. Shading is set to GLSL, and the objects are UV mapped and textured. It seems that vertex paint is overriding the material for the object even though it is unchecked in the material options.
[image]

Shading is set to GLSL
[image]

Objects have a texture applied
[image]

Comment: I was having the same problem and it did fix but it made half of the place empty or something in a game I was working on. [This is how it looks when it's not rendered.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6f5Ux.jpg) [This is how it looks when it is rendered .](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M592h.jpg) [This is how the lamp settings look like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZuT9.jpg) [This is how the shading settings look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/orcjT.jpg)

Answer (score 8):

Your problem is Very simple to fix. Currently, your shading is set to solid. Change it to textured view, and your textures will display.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Set the Shading to "Texture" then start the engine

[image: Texture]

Comment: You beat me to it by exactly one minute! I was making the .gif for a better reference, so It is possible (but un-likely) that I could have started writing my answer before you.......