# when i press "p" it doesnt play my game

Tags: game-engine

I am making a game in blender and when I press p to test my game, the screen goes white and when I press escape it goes back to normal and I don't know if my game is working or not.

Comment: switch to tectured veiw

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/34116/599