# BGE - Model is white instead of it's given textures

Tags: texturing, game-engine

I am trying to make a game in BGE, but when I play, the models are all bright white.

I read on a forum that you have to change the shading to GLSL, but it stayed white.

.blend file:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [BGE everything white in playmode](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34116/bge-everything-white-in-playmode)

Answer (score 1):

I can guess only, but maybe the 3D view is in solid shading mode. Try to switch to textured mode, you should see textures then.

So, change the mode from

[image: Solid Shading Mode]

which results in:

[image: Ingame View of Solid Mode]

to:

[image: Textured Shading Mode]

which results in:

[image: Ingame View of Textured Mode]

**EDIT**: After seeing your file, I think the behavior you described comes from another few problems:

- The ground material's Emit setting is set to 2, which makes the material emissive and therefore it's not interacting with lamps.
- There are no lamps in the scene.
- The texture on the ground plane is just plain white, you can just use the material color for that. The player object has that texture too.

Comment: I added my file to the post, maybe you could give instructions with screenshots, it would be very well appreciated.

Comment: @Angyeet I've updated my answer, I hope it's better now